# Babel 7 with Express

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs

I am trying to use Babel 7 with Express and I have resolved all errors that have come my way, but I cannot get the Express server to start. I'm unsure if this is because there is no substitute (to my knowledge) for babel-node or if I am doing something wrong.

Here is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "MEAN-Package",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A package for the exercises",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Chasen Bettinger",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js --exec babel"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.6.6",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.2"
  }
}
```

Here is server.js

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:3000/");

export { app as default };
```

My .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Console output:

[image: Console Output]

Trying to learn express so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You should you `babel-node` instead of `babel`. Follow these steps to fix it:

Add babel-node:

```
 yarn add @babel/node --dev
```

2- Change your start script on `package.json` to:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon server.js --exec babel-node",
}
```

Comment: why do you need babel node?  shouldn't you be able to use babel-register?  Just that people don't know how to do this with Babel 7 in terms of syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using babel-node in production. It is unnecessarily heavy, with high memory usage due to the cache being stored in memory. You will also always experience a startup performance penalty as the entire app needs to be compiled on the fly.

the correct way is:

```
npm i -D @babel/node
```

and

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon server.js --exec babel-node",
}

npm run start
```